# Link to or highlight particular Google search result

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a VB.net tool that takes in two strings from the user: a string to search Google with, and the website domain to look for. Inputted domains are masked with * (like G**gle.com) so I replace "*" with "." which will match any character in Regex.

The tool checks the source of every Google result page (up to page 50) and links the user once it finds a match:

```
    'Search string
    Dim strSearch As String = InputBox("Enter search string", "Search string")

    'Website to look for
    Dim strWebsite As String = InputBox("Enter website to look for", "website")

    'Remote any trailing or leading spaces
    strSearch = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strSearch).Trim
    strWebsite = strWebsite.Replace("*", ".").Trim

    Dim wbClient As New WebClient
    For i As Integer = 1 To 50
        'The Google results page
        Dim strURL As String = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & strSearch & "&start=" & i * 10

        'Get page source of the results page
        Dim strResults As String = wbClient.DownloadString(strURL)

        'If the current page includes the website we're looking for then
        If Regex.IsMatch(strResults, strWebsite, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) Then
            MsgBox("Page " & i)

            'Open the page
            Process.Start(strURL)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

This code will open the correct page, but I would like it to scroll to the matched Google result (kind of like when you anchor link to a target on the same page with html using a #).

Does Google have any URL parameters I can use to achieve this, or do each of the results have an ID I can add to the URL after a #? I spent a while searching but could not find anything. If not, I'll have to think of something else or skip it entirely.

Comment: Did you try inspecting the source code of Google's search results page to find that out yourself?

Comment: Yeah. I figured the answer was in there somewhere but had trouble finding it, that's why I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the little dropdown arrow on each search result URL (see image) has an id of `am-b0`, where the `0` is the index of the result.  You'll have to play around with different methods to get the correct index for the regex match, but I think that should work.

This picture is the first (index `0`) search result for the URL:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=test
```

Obviously, this is a pretty brittle solution, because google could change something on their end at any time to break this:

[image: ID of search result]

Just in case it's not clear, linking to this result would be:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=test#am-b0
```

Comment: Oh, seems that not all the results have that but it looks like it's the best I'm going to get. I don't know why I didn't just ctrl+F "id=" in the source code before, my brain wasn't functioning earlier.

Comment: You're right.  Bummer.  Maybe use a WebBrowser Control instead of `Process.Start` to the user's browser so you can control the scroll position.

Comment: This link might help with that: http://www.bunkovdenis.com/2015/07/find-select-and-scroll-to-text-in.html

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using a WebBrowser controler since it's slower, but it looks like that's my best option here. Thanks guys.